Extra Page When Printing Web Pages in Lightning Experience
When printing web pages in Lightning Experience, there is always an extra page. This is true for any Record pages, App Pages from Lightning Component or Lightning Page Tabs.
Adding css in Lightning Component Tab as test revealed that there are mysterious div that exceeds the first page, hence producing the second page. Any solutions to remove them from printing?
Printing the page in Google Chrome (Ctrl + P):

When opening with a PDF reader:

CSS:
@media print {
  div { border: 1px solid black; } 
}

JS:
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader'
import RESOURCE from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/test';

export default class Test extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {
        Promise.all([
            loadStyle(this, RESOURCE + '/test.css')
        ]);
    }
}

XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>59.0</apiVersion>
        <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>


I tested "Save to PDF" and "Microsoft Print to PDF" in Google Chrome on a couple pages (Home, and a Record Detail page), and they do not feature this mystery div. This is some kind of customization or maybe a custom component in a utility bar or something. Unfortunately, you'll have to identify the element in the UI/DOM before you can figure out how to remove it from the PDF printout.
